# Mysql Query depending on the version of mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I am facing one issue, Post mysql 5.7 `information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS` is deprecated instead of this they are using `performance_schema.global_status`.

So I would like to know depending on MySQL version how to query a particular table.

I know `Select @@version` gives me the version of mysql.

```
  SELECT * FROM performance_schema.global_status
            WHERE VARIABLE_VALUE REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$'.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ideally we update the queries as per breaking changes in a new version!

Comment: What is the context in which you need to run this query?  A stored proc, a function, a script?  Clearly, you could execute the correct query from the command line by yourself.

Comment: One option is to use a [14.5 Prepared SQL Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PMNx6vwxNerug3DDW6Fiy/1) example.

Comment: Not looking like procedure or function. Want SQL query.

Comment: any prepared statement for this problem , my basic query is              
 SELECT
                    
                    LOWER(VARIABLE_NAME) AS "p_name",
                    VARIABLE_VALUE AS "value",
                FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS
                WHERE VARIABLE_VALUE REGEXP "^-?[0-9]+$"';

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your querying the database from outside of a MySQL shell (say, PHP) in the context of this answer. Why don't you try adding the version number of the later release in conditional comments (Note I haven't had time to try this)? Detailed [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html) and [here](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2007/05/22/how-to-write-mysql-conditional-comments/).

This means the first query would look like this, but only return results on versions of MySQL after 4.1.22:

```
/*!40122 SELECT col FROM mytable;*/
```

In the case there are results then these can be used as planned in your program and if not then you could use an `if` to execute the earlier version syntax like so:

```
SELECT differentSyntaxCol FROM mytable;
```

Note this can be adapted to cascade down a number of versions of MySQL if working with several versions, but as there is no syntax for 'below version X', you need to start with the newest and work down.

Regards,

James

Comment: Ya agree, but using two query for different version one will work and other fail, that is the last option i wanted to do. if we can do IF-ELSE in query , that will be great.

Comment: Not an option as far as I'm aware, 1) The parser is going to error on out of date syntax, and 2) for flow control `IF ELSE` can only be used inside stored procedures. Can you post the actual query? There may be a way forward commenting specific parts using conditional comments. Note if the first query above works, the second would never be run and therefore wouldn't fail.

Comment: Above 5.6 SELECT * FROM performance_schema.global_status
            WHERE VARIABLE_VALUE REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$'. and             below                SELECT * FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS
            WHERE VARIABLE_VALUE REGEXP '^-?[0-9]+$'.