# MySQL - How to only run statement if DB version is LESS THAN a given version?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to construct a set of database migrations, in which I'm hoping to include [some polyfill functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58015720/451726) for MySQL versions prior to MySQL 8. I've found a way to use [conditional comments to only run code if it is *above* the given version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43785381/451726), but how can I do the opposite, and only run the code if it is, for example, any version below 8?

These migrations will be in a `.sql` file with multiple statements, so the solution need not be contained to a single statement.

My current ideas are:

1. Somehow use an if/else or case/when statement to run the code, if it's possible to do checking within a statement, like this (pseudocode):

```sql
SELECT "statements that will be run for any version up here" AS example;

IF @version < 80000
  SELECT "This only gets run on versions prior to 8" AS example;
ELSE 
  /* do nothing */
END
```

2. Stop execution of the script early without raising an error, perhaps using the conditional comments (again, pseudocode):

```sql
SELECT "statements that will be run for any version up here" AS example;

/*!80000 EXIT */

/* only MySQL 5 code after this */
SELECT "This only gets run on versions prior to 8" AS example;
```

3. Some other method?

So, basically, how can I only run code for versions of MySQL less than version 8? If option 1, how should I check the version and conditionally execute statements? If option 2, how can I stop execution of multiple statements, **without raising an error**, like a MySQL equivalent to a `BREAK` statement? Or otherwise, is there some better method I haven't found yet?